# Array with a blank reult

Tags: java, arrays, hash, nlp

why can execute my code without any issues and it gives me the correct results.

```
    package com.opennlp.demo;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import opennlp.tools.cmdline.parser.ParserTool;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parse;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parser;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserFactory;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserModel;

public class ParserTest {

    public static Set<String> nounPhrases = new HashSet<>();



    private static String line = "I need a PHP note if";

    public void getNounPhrases(Parse p) {
        if (p.getType().equals("NN") || p.getType().equals("NNS") || p.getType().equals("NNP") || p.getType().equals("NNPS")) {
             nounPhrases.add(p.getCoveredText());
             //System.out.println(p.getCoveredText());
        }



        for (Parse child : p.getChildren()) {
             getNounPhrases(child);
             System.out.println(child.toString()+"lol");
        }
    }


    public void parserAction() throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
        ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);
        Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
        Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(line, parser, 1);
        for (Parse p : topParses){
            //p.show();
            getNounPhrases(p);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          new ParserTest().parserAction();
          System.out.println("List of Noun Parse : "+nounPhrases);

         }


}
```

below is my second code.. it gives me a blank Array in console.I removed main method from above class and I tried to print the nounPhrases inside another class. it shows a blank array. I think in second code my parserAction method is not executing. How can I do execute that method without a main method in another class ?

my second code

```
    package com.opennlp.demo;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import opennlp.tools.cmdline.parser.ParserTool;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parse;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parser;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserFactory;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserModel;

public class ParserTest {

    public static Set<String> nounPhrases = new HashSet<>();


    //private static String line = "i need a Java book which has JSP also";

    private static String line = "I need a PHP note if";

    public void getNounPhrases(Parse p) {
        if (p.getType().equals("NN") || p.getType().equals("NNS") || p.getType().equals("NNP") || p.getType().equals("NNPS")) {
             nounPhrases.add(p.getCoveredText());
             //System.out.println(p.getCoveredText());
        }



        for (Parse child : p.getChildren()) {
             getNounPhrases(child);
             System.out.println(child.toString()+"lol");
        }
    }


    public void parserAction() throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
        ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);
        Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
        Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(line, parser, 1);
        for (Parse p : topParses){
            //p.show();
            getNounPhrases(p);
        }
    }




}
```

I called the nounPhrases in another class like below. But it shows a blank result. How to fix this ? I need to do this without a main method in this class.

```
ParserTest pt = new ParserTest();

                    pt.parserAction();

                    System.out.println(ParserTest.nounPhrases);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please read and follow the
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: your main method is your entry point for the program. You cant run your code without a main method. Maybe if you are using java inside some other environment or framework like Android or Spring then this statement might not be true, but for just regular Java code, you need a main method. You can put the main method in its own class, it doesnt have to be in your ParserTest class

Comment: Why did you make the `nounPhrases` Set static?

Comment: Have clear separation of concerns in your methods. Your code is looking quite messy and is painful to follow.

Comment: Avoid using public fields and direct access to them. It violates the most importand OO principle *information hiding/encapsulation* also avid *public* static  fields (when they are not `final` too) because [global variables are evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Comment: I'm a beginner to java.please suggest me a way to access this noun nounPhrases in another class. without executing main method